# Laravel with Angular Request Issue

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I've this on my Laravel controller:

```
    public function store(CreateRequest $request)
    {
        // Create a random password
        $password    = str_random(6);
        $encPassword = bcrypt($password);

        // Add password to the request to save it on createOrUpdate method
        $request->request->add(['password' => $encPassword]);

        dd($request->all());

    }
```

If I made a request from postman I get the right response, like:

```
array:3 [
  "email" => "darthvader4@app.com"
  "roles" => "1"
  "password" => "$2y$10$qdnk6TX09pxd35v5mvTtfOEChV3ADbV0h3Q2WSc8g4R7F2UbuoENu"
]
```

but when I try to make the request from the angular application, this is the response I get:

```
array:2 [
  "email" => "mcarvalho@example.com",
  "roles" => "1"
]
```

Anyone have an ideia why the `$request->request->add['password' => $encPassword]);` is not working on angular app?

## Headers for postman

Accept application/json

Content-Type application/json

## Headers from Angular application

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*

Content-Type:application/json

## PS

If I do this `dd($request->request->all());` it works for both Angular and Postman, but doesn't make any sense to me why works on one and on the other don't.

If I use `$request->query->add(['password' => $encPassword]);` it works!

Thank you all!

Comment: what is the error you get in console? If its CORS related then you have to handle CORS issues on your laravel side,

Comment: Hi, no errors on the console. Doesn't seem a CORS problem since I'm using a package for Laravel and an Chrome CORS extension for Angular.